# How can I remove special characters from a string without using any external library?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know there's the unicode library, but I don't want to import anything (this is for an assignment where importing libraries loses points).

Let's say I have this string `"àèéùùìssaààò"` and the desired output would be `"aeeuuissaaao"`. Is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258623/remove-special-characters-from-string

Comment: This makes me import unicode, but I don't want to import anything

Comment: And what exactly is the reason why you don't want to import a module that comes standard with Python?

Comment: It's for an assigment, I lose 5 points every time I import something. The score is out of 10. 6/10 is the minimum for pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast approach that will scan the string once

```
string = "àèéùùìssaààò"
lookup = {"à": "a", "è": "e", "é": "e", "ù": "u", "ò": "o", "ì": "i"}
clean_string = ''.join(lookup.get(x, x) for x in string)
print(clean_string)
```

output

```
aeeuuissaaao
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work.

```
string = "àèéùùìssaààò"
string = string.replace("à", "a")
string = string.replace("è", "e")
string = string.replace("é", "e")
string = string.replace("ù", "u")
string = string.replace("ò", "o")
string = string.replace("ì", "i")
print(string)
```

you can use string.replace method to replace accents.
you can use string.replace like this `string.replace(old, new, [count])`

a little easy way

```
string = "àèéùùìssaààò"
replacelist = ["à", "è" ,"é", "ù", "ò", "ì"] # add the accent to here
correctlist = ["a", "e", "e", "u", "o", "i"] # add the normal English to here
for i in range(len(replacelist)):
    string = string.replace(replacelist[i], correctlist[i])
print(string)
```

this is using a for loop so it's a little more easy.
you just need to add something to the replacelist, and the correctlist.

Comment: There is no way to do that without hardcoding the letters I have to change?

Comment: @KrankenWagen Edited so there is more easy way. but I think there is no way to do this without importing something and not hardcoding the letters you have to change.